# Mongoose query/schema error only in docker container

Tags: docker, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database which I am querying with Mongoose.

I am using a collection `audits` to store information about update changes, failed logins and errors.

**Audit Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const auditSchema = new Schema({
  ref: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  linkedId: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    refPath: 'ref'
  },
  action: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['insert', 'update', 'delete', 'special']
  },
  /* ... lots more fields */
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('audit', auditSchema);
```

Querying this collection in my docker container using the query below:

```
return Audit.find().sort({date: -1})
  .skip(skipInt)
  .limit(limitInt)
  .populate('user')
  .populate('linkedId')
  .exec();
```

I receive the following error:

```
Schema hasn't been registered for model "error". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

There isn't an "error" schema however I've checked that all the entries in the collection with a `ref` of error don't have a `linkedId` populated:

```
{ref: 'error', linkedId: {$exists: true}} // 0 documents
```

I don't understand why this works fine on my dev system (win 10, vscode debugging) but errors in both my local docker as well as aws lamda.

I've run a complete re-build of the docker images to try and make sure it wasn't a caching issue but still the error remains.

**edit**

Tried the two docker files, both exhibit the same behavior, building on a windows 10 machine

```
FROM node:8-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i --quiet
COPY . .
RUN npm install pm2 -g
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "./bin/www"]


FROM node:12
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN wget https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/5.4.7.2/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.4.7.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz -O libo.tar.gz
RUN apt update \
  && apt install -y libxinerama1 libfontconfig1 libdbus-glib-1-2 libcairo2 libcups2 libglu1-mesa libsm6 unzip \
  && tar -zxvf libo.tar.gz
WORKDIR /tmp/LibreOffice_5.4.7.2_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS
RUN dpkg -i *.deb
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json .
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
RUN npm i --quiet
COPY . .
RUN npm install pm2 -g
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "./bin/www"]
```

**edit 2**

I think I have found the difference but not a solution, the container shows mongoose version `5.9.28` however package.json listed `^5.8.3`, updating `mongoose` to version `5.9.28` gives the same error on my local installation, however now I'm stuck with the same error and no clue how to solve it.

Comment: A rights issue when you build your docker image? What's the origin of the docker image? Did you modify it? Lots of grey zones.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I've added two docker files I have tried (old and new), I'm not sure if that gives enough information. I still don't understand how mongoose behaviour is different between the two environments, both connected to the same database, processing the same data. It makes no sense.

Comment: are you using multiple connections?

Comment: @Nonik I am using a single `mongoose.connect` however it is connecting to a 3 node cluster, so I'm not sure on the answer to that.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I've found the difference and added to the question, however I still need to resolve the error

Comment: @Nonik I've found the difference and added to the question, however I still need to resolve the error

Comment: try Replace depends_on with links in your docker-compose.yml and try to run command again

Comment: @Nonik I don't have a `docker-compose.yml`, just the dockerfile

Comment: Have you tried defining an empty model for 'error', just to see if that fixes it?

Comment: @JohnnyHK This bypassed the error as per yours and Dimple Patel's suggestion, annoying that this is necessary in newer versions.

Comment: Agreed. Probably worth reporting: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues

Comment: @JohnnyHK Reported and confirmed as a bug https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware about *Docker* or *AWS Lambda* but I have checked your `auditSchema` and query in simple *Node.js* *express* app and same error reproduce at my end as well.

```
MissingSchemaError:Schema hasn't been registered for model "error". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

So the problem is: the `linkedId` property declared in `auditSchema` as `refpath:ref` that means it will populate from multiple collections based on the value of a `ref` property in the document. So when we query `Audit.find().populate('linkedId')` it fetch all record from `Audit` collection and populate `linkedId` for each document. If document contain value `ref:error` then *mongoose* try to look for `error` collection for population and we don't have any error schema or error collection so it will cause above error.

This error will be generated for each document in your `Audit` collection whose `ref` field contains value other than `error` as well. *Mongoose* needed all schema/collection exist which you've specified as value of `ref`.

To solve this problem you need to define collection for each value you've provided in `ref` property of `Audit` documents

Please refer [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref) to know more about `refpath`.

Comment: I defined an empty error as: `const Error = new mongoose.model('error', new mongoose.Schema({err: Object}));` and this bypasses the schema error, annoying that this is necessary in 5.9 but not in 5.8, in 5.8 it didn't try and populate if the value was undefined, I don't see any reason for it, but thank you none the less.